# Why jQuery does not add the class "drop1"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, async-await

I wrote a code for a mobile navigation with sub-menus and tried to add a Class using jQuery and javascript but both methods didn´t adad the Class "drop1" or "drop2" to the clicked element.

I´ve already tried to catch the error, but there was no one

```
$("ul#main-menu > li[class ^= level1-]")
    .prev("img")
    .addBack()
    .on("click", async ()=> {
        try {
            await $(this).addClass("drop1");
            cl2 = this;
            cl2.className += "drop1";
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    })
    .each((i, elem)=> {
        if($(elem).hasClass("drop1")) {
            let newElem = $(elem);
            if($(elem).is("img")) {
                newElem = $(elem).closest("li");
                $(elem).removeClass("drop1");
                newElem.addClass("drop1");
            }
        } else {
            return;
        }
        newElem
            .nextUntil("li")
            .animate({
                "transform": "rotate(180deg)"
            }, 300);
        newElem
            .children("ul[class $= m1]")
            .slideDown(300)
            .children("li[href = #]")
            .on("click", async ()=> {
                try {
                    await $(this).addClass("drop2");
                    cl1 = this;
                    cl1.className += "drop2";
                } catch(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            })
            .each((i, el)=> {
                if($(el).hasClass("drop2")) {
                    newEL = $(el);
                } else {
                    return;
                }
                newEL
                    .children("ul")
                    .slideDown(300);
            });
    });
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem here by adding the HTML? Also why are you async-awaiting in the click event?

Comment: What is `this` ? Also `addClass` is not async, `await` is senseless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is not the clicked element. `this` inside an arrow function is the same as outside the arrow function, in this case it is probably `window`. `addClass` is synchronous, using `await` on it is a no op.

```
  /*...*/.on("click", function() {
        $(this).addClass("drop1");
 });
```

PS: Unhandled errors will bubble up, and will finally be shown in the console. Adding a `try { } catch` only makes sense if you really want to handle it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Arrow_functions

Comment: The alternative is simply avoiding the use of `this`. Eg. `.on('click', event => $(event.target).addClass('drop1'))`